# How to set VSS (Shadow Copy) Retention

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008, volume-shadow-copy, vss

I am in the process of optimizing the VSS on our Windows Server 2008 SP2 machine.

I would like to do the following:

Run a snapshot at 11:59 AM and 11:59 PM every day

- Keep a retention of 30 days for this

After 30 days, keep only a weekly snapshot for the Sunday at 11:59 PM until the VSS disc space is consumed.

How would I go about setting the retention for these scheduled tasks?